# Razor Pages RedirectToPage("/") causes error "No page named '/' matches the supplied values"

Tags: razor-pages

In a brand new out-of-the-box asp.net core RazorPages project, why does the following result in the exception "InvalidOperationException: No page named '/' matches the supplied values"?

```
public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    return RedirectToPage("/");
}
```

I would expect it to redirect to /Index. `RedirectToPage("")` and `RedirectToPage("Index")` work as expected, but in this case I'm being passed a return url of "/". I know I could just check for "/" and replace it with "" but it seems like this should work.

Comment: Actually I've now realized that RedirectToPage("") just sends me back to the current page, so I would need to replace "/" with "Index".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `RedirectToPage()` method is referring to a Razor cshtml "page" rather than a html page in the browser. So it expects the parameter to refer to a cshtml page in your project. e.g.

```cs
public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    // Redirect to Index.cshtml in folder above
    return RedirectToPage("../Index");
}
```

That's why "/" is not valid with this method.

If you want to redirect to a url you can use `Redirect()` e.g.

```cs
public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    return Redirect("~/");
}
```